# How to put a input and a button in a row?

Tags: ratchet-bootstrap, ratchet-2

code：

```
<div class="input-row">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Search"><button class="btn" >重发</button>
 </div>
```

result in browser：

URL : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/goratchet/8crWEoqStYI

Why the button at the first of the row? Can i put the button end of the row? any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the property `float` to position it right or left

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div style="width: 1000px; height: 600px; border: 1px solid red; position: absolute">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Search" style="float: left">

      <button style="float:right">MyButton</button>
    </div>
  <body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="input-row">
    <div style="float:left;">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search">
    </div>
    <div style="float:right;">
        <button class="btn" >重发</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

hopefully this will work, i dont know the rest of your css rules